# How to reload ASP 1.0 page with additional parameter

Tags: javascript, html, excel, asp-classic

I'm a beginner of ASP.  I'm maintaining at ASP 1.0 page and I want to reload the page with an additional parameter when user click client-side URL.  Its important that it also keeps the current parameters.

The objective is to export the table currently display in Excel.  So I want to reload the page with a special parameter that would tell the page to change the ResponseType to be Excel data.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript simply reference the page, but with query string param.

```
window.location = "myPage.asp?newParam=newValue";
```

Comment: Would that keep the previous params ?

Comment: You need make sure you always append the previous params as well in the URL.

Comment: Nope, but this would:

window.location = window.location + "&newParam=newValue"

Comment: javascript: window.location = window.location.href+'&export=1'

Answer (score 0):

Would [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried using querystring? you can reload the same page with something like 
SomePage.asp?param=value. And check in the code something like test = Request["param"] and then use the "test" variable. You can load the page using window.location = 'SomePage.asp?param=value'.